# Oracle Update Statement: trouble with valid date check

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

So I'm working on fixing up a table (we'll call this 'test') with thousands of entries that needs data cleaning.  The column (we'll call this 'textlog') of the table I'm fixing up is currently a varchar2 datatype.  Usually the column starts with a date in any number of formats followed by a description of some sort like the examples below:

```
03/01/05-randomtext randomtext
03/01/2005 - randomtext randomtext
03/1/05//randomtext randomtext
03/1/2005 randomtext randomtext
3.01.2005 randomtext randomtext
3.01.05//randomtext randomtext
3-1-05 - randomtext randomtext
3-1-2005 randomtext randomtext
2005/03/01 - randomtext randomtext
2005/3/1//randomtext randomtext
2005.3.01 randomtext randomtext
2005-03-1 randomtext randomtext
```

All this data was entered manually, which is why it's in this nightmare of a format.  However, as shown above, the ONLY characters ever separating the months, days, and years are '/', '-', or '.'

What I need to do is change all the data in this column so that if it starts with a  date it is changed to the format RRRR/MM/DD and then followed by the string of text (still contained within the same column).  So the data above would need to look like this when I'm through with it:

```
2005/03/01 randomtext randomtext
```

Some columns start with text first, but all these can be ignored.  I'm only concerned with entries that start with a date.  The problem I'm running into is sometimes someone made a huge mistake entering data and put in an invalid date (january 0 for example) and my query is stopping there.  I can't be sure how many invalid dates there are or which entries they are exactly, so it would be best to just ignore these as well.

Below is my current query that is running into problems when an invalid date is encountered.  As I'm sure you'll be able to tell from my code, I'm pretty new to SQL, so I would appreciate any help you can provide, whether it be working with my current code are suggesting an altogether different approach.

Note - the code is set up this way to cover all the current formats dates appear (covered above in my example)

```
update test
set logtext = REPLACE(logtext, substr(logtext, 1, 10), to_char(to_date(substr(logtext, 1, 10), 'MM/DD/RRRR'), 'RRRR/MM/DD'))
    where regexp_like(logtext, '^[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][^0-9]')
    or    regexp_like(logtext, '^[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][^0-9]')
    or    regexp_like(logtext, '^[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][^0-9]');

update test
set logtext = REPLACE(logtext, substr(logtext, 1, 9), to_char(to_date(substr(logtext, 1, 9), 'MM/DD/RRRR'), 'RRRR/MM/DD'))
    where regexp_like(logtext, '^[0-9][0-9]/[0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][^0-9]')
    or    regexp_like(logtext, '^[0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][^0-9]')
    or    regexp_like(logtext, '^[0-9][0-9]-[0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][^0-9]')
    or    regexp_like(logtext, '^[0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][^0-9]')
    or    regexp_like(logtext, '^[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][^0-9]')
    or    regexp_like(logtext, '^[0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][^0-9]');

update test
set logtext = REPLACE(logtext, substr(logtext, 1, 8), to_char(to_date(substr(logtext, 1, 8), 'MM/DD/RRRR'), 'RRRR/MM/DD'))
    where regexp_like(logtext, '^[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][^0-9]')
    or    regexp_like(logtext, '^[0-9]/[0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][^0-9]')
    or    regexp_like(logtext, '^[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][^0-9]')
    or    regexp_like(logtext, '^[0-9]-[0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][^0-9]')
    or    regexp_like(logtext, '^[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9][^0-9]')
    or    regexp_like(logtext, '^[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][^0-9]');

update test
set logtext = REPLACE(logtext, substr(logtext, 1, 7), to_char(to_date(substr(logtext, 1, 7), 'MM/DD/RRRR'), 'RRRR/MM/DD'))
    where regexp_like(logtext, '^[0-9][0-9]/[0-9]/[0-9][0-9][^0-9]')
    or    regexp_like(logtext, '^[0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][^0-9]')
    or    regexp_like(logtext, '^[0-9][0-9]-[0-9]-[0-9][0-9][^0-9]')
    or    regexp_like(logtext, '^[0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][^0-9]')
    or    regexp_like(logtext, '^[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9][0-9][^0-9]')
    or    regexp_like(logtext, '^[0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9][^0-9]');

update test
set logtext = REPLACE(logtext, substr(logtext, 1, 6), to_char(to_date(substr(logtext, 1, 6), 'MM/DD/RRRR'), 'RRRR/MM/DD'))
    where regexp_like(logtext, '^[0-9]/[0-9]/[0-9][0-9][^0-9]')
    or    regexp_like(logtext, '^[0-9]-[0-9]-[0-9][0-9][^0-9]')
    or    regexp_like(logtext, '^[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9][0-9][^0-9]');

update test
set logtext = REPLACE(logtext, substr(logtext, 1, 10), to_char(to_date(substr(logtext, 1, 10), 'RRRR/MM/DD'), 'RRRR/MM/DD'))
    where regexp_like(logtext, '^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][^0-9]')
    or    regexp_like(logtext, '^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][^0-9]')
    or    regexp_like(logtext, '^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9][^0-9]');

update test
set logtext = REPLACE(logtext, substr(logtext, 1, 9), to_char(to_date(substr(logtext, 1, 9), 'RRRR/MM/DD'), 'RRRR/MM/DD'))
    where regexp_like(logtext, '^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][^0-9]')
    or    regexp_like(logtext, '^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9]/[0-9][0-9][^0-9]')
    or    regexp_like(logtext, '^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][^0-9]')
    or    regexp_like(logtext, '^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9]-[0-9][0-9][^0-9]')
    or    regexp_like(logtext, '^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][^0-9]')
    or    regexp_like(logtext, '^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9][0-9][^0-9]');

update test
set logtext = REPLACE(logtext, substr(logtext, 1, 8), to_char(to_date(substr(logtext, 1, 8), 'RRRR/MM/DD'), 'RRRR/MM/DD'))
    where regexp_like(logtext, '^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9]/[0-9][^0-9]')
    or    regexp_like(logtext, '^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9]-[0-9][^0-9]')
    or    regexp_like(logtext, '^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9][^0-9]');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Create table T_53337_tmp (unparsed varchar(100)); --input



insert into T_53337_tmp values('03/01/05-randomtext randomtext');
insert into T_53337_tmp values('03/01/2005 - randomtext randomtext');
insert into T_53337_tmp values('03/1/05//randomtext randomtext');
insert into T_53337_tmp values('03/1/2005 randomtext randomtext');
insert into T_53337_tmp values('3.01.2005 randomtext randomtext');
insert into T_53337_tmp values('3.01.05//randomtext randomtext');
insert into T_53337_tmp values('3-1-05 - randomtext randomtext');
insert into T_53337_tmp values('3-1-2005 randomtext randomtext');
insert into T_53337_tmp values('2005/03/01 - randomtext randomtext');
insert into T_53337_tmp values('2005/3/1//randomtext randomtext');
insert into T_53337_tmp values('2005.3.01 randomtext randomtext');
insert into T_53337_tmp values('2005-03-1 randomtext randomtext');


Update T_53337_tmp  set unparsed= REGEXP_REPLACE(unparsed,
                        '^([0-9]+)([. /-]+)([0-9]+)([. /-]+)([0-9]+)([. /-]+)(.*)$'
                          ,'\1-\3-\5');
```

at this stage you have data as below

```
03-01-05        
03-01-2005  
03-1-05     
03-1-2005   
3-01-2005   
3-01-05     
3-1-05      
3-1-2005    
2005-03-01  
2005-3-1    
2005-3-01   
2005-03-1
```

***One other important thing here is that you may parse incorrect values. If you get 02-01-12 it could be 02-Jan-2012 or 01-Feb-2012 or even 12-Jan-2002.***

After you have figured out how to solve above logical issue:
Use a custom function to check the validity of the date.

(from https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:890580198758)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MY2DATE (p_str IN VARCHAR2
  ,format_picture IN VARCHAR2
)
   RETURN DATE
IS
BEGIN
   RETURN TO_DATE(p_str, format_picture);
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      RETURN NULL;
END;
/
```

Your final update statement will be (example for only one case DD-MM-YYYY from input is below; You may need to write one update each for each format you decide is valid from above.) (SQL NOT TESTED)

```
Update T_53337_tmp  
set unparsed= 
to_char(MY2DATE(unparsed,'DD-MM-YYYY'),'YYYY/MM/DD') 
where MY2DATE(unparsed,'DD-MM-YYYY') is not null;
```

(assuming the final uniform format you need is 'YYYY/MM/DD')

Comment: I think I'm not quite understanding what you mean.  Once again I'm fairly new to SQL so I kind of need my hand held through the process haha.  I don't think I mentioned I'm using Oracle, but I'm guessing that was implied through PL/SQL being mentioned in the title.

I've already copied the table over using a 'create table as' statement for checking that my queries work.  Do you mean to only load a little data into that table at a time and then do updates?  I don't understand how to use the ISDATE() part.

Sorry, I wish I understood better :(

Comment: ISDATE() was for ms sql server. Oracle doesnt have an equivalent so youneed to use a new custom function. try along the lines of above, I have tested initial regexp but not the custom function. Le us know if it works or not

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply.  My project requirements took a turn and I went a completely different route.  Basically I improved my selections and had to change invalid dates to the last days of months or first, depending on the situation.  If you're interested in my changes (which worked) I can send you a PM detailing the route I took.  Thanks for the help though, it was informative (and I ended up using your date check function)  Again, sorry for the rather late response.

Comment: No Problem, post your answer here so that it would be useful for some one else. And if my answer was helpful, please vote it up too ;)